# GTK+ SpinButton value is always min

Tags: c, gtk

I'm currently working in an assigment using GTk+ on Linux. My question is very very simple:
I have two SpinButtons, defined as such:

```
void editor_pedir_datos(GtkWidget * ventana, gpointer layout_editor){
    GtkWidget *cajav;
    GtkWidget *labelfilas;
    GtkWidget *labelcolumnas;
    GtkWidget *botonenviar;


    cajav = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL,10);
    spinfilas = gtk_spin_button_new_with_range(2,15,1);

    spincolumnas = gtk_spin_button_new_with_range(4,15,1);

    ventana_datos = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(ventana_datos),GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(ventana_datos), "Ingresar Datos");

    labelfilas = gtk_label_new("Filas:");

    labelcolumnas = gtk_label_new("Columnas:");



    botonenviar = gtk_button_new_with_label("Aceptar");

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(cajav), labelfilas,0,0,0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(cajav), spinfilas,0,0,0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(cajav), labelcolumnas,0,0,0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(cajav), spincolumnas,0,0,0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(cajav), botonenviar,0,0,0);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (ventana_datos), cajav);
    gtk_widget_show_all(ventana_datos);
    g_signal_connect(botonenviar, "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK(editor_nuevo_nivel_con_datos), NULL);

}
```

Both spinbuttons and the window "ventana_datos" are global pointers. On a callback function for a button, I have the reading of the values:

```
void editor_nuevo_nivel_con_datos(GtkWidget * ventana, gpointer data){

    int columnas_sp = gtk_spin_button_get_value_as_int(GTK_SPIN_BUTTON(spincolumnas));
    int filas_sp = gtk_spin_button_get_value_as_int(GTK_SPIN_BUTTON(spinfilas));

    g_print("Filas: %d Columnas: %d\n", filas_sp, columnas_sp);
    gtk_widget_destroy(ventana_datos);
    nivel_mod = malloc(sizeof(struct nivel));
    nuevo_nivel_vacio(nivel_mod, filas_sp, columnas_sp);
    editor_cargar_nivel(nivel_mod);

}
```

The problem is: `filas_sp` is indeed the right value entered in the spinbutton. However, `columnas_sp` is always the minimum value on the spinbutton range (4), no matter what value the user entered on the spinbutton. Is this some feature/configuration that I'm missing?

I cannot find anything in the API related to this, and I would appreciate any help.

**EDIT**: Ok, some more info. I'm packing the spinbuttons on a box:

```
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(cajav), labelfilas,0,0,0);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(cajav), spinfilas,0,0,0);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(cajav), labelcolumnas,0,0,0);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(cajav), spincolumnas,0,0,0);
```

The labels are just some labels to indicate what the spinbuttons are for. If I pack them on a reverse order:

```
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(cajav), labelcolumnas,0,0,0);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(cajav), spincolumnas,0,0,0);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(cajav), labelfilas,0,0,0);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(cajav), spinfilas,0,0,0);
```

Now it's the other spinbutton which reports only the minimum value.

**EDIT:**: Added the whole functions.

Comment: As you can see from [this minimal sample](http://snipt.org/AaaI4) that spin buttons do work correctly. Maybe you can post the whole code if possible or smallest snippet which causes your problem

Comment: Done, added the two functions. I'm working on GTK+ 3.

Comment: The most probable reason for your problem is a typo in the callback function. You have `filas_sp` twice instead of `filas_sp` & `columnas_sp`. Unless its a typo entering the code in the question, most likely it might be the root cause of your problem. I would also recommend that you try to adhere to the callback function signature for the signals i.e. for `button-press-event` it is `gboolean foo(GtkWidget *, GdkEvent*, gpointer)`. Try to stick to the signature as many a times signature mismatch is cause of the problem (not in this case though)

Comment: My bad, actually that's the "patch" I used since the proyect was due this sunday. I made it such that the values were both taken from the first spinbutton, since it was the one that worked. I will try to modify the callback signature :-)

Comment: Modifying callback *might* not help in this case. Why not try to create a minimal program with two spin buttons based on your code and check (seems to work here). The problem could be creeping in from other parts of the code.

Comment: Already did that, along with the example you kindly provided me. It works on a minimal program. As you say, probably the problem is coming from another part, but I can't possibly guess from where, and the whole project is sightly above the thousand lines of code, so I can't post it all in here.

Comment: Any thought on what part of the code may be useful for me to post?

Comment: Hmm, can you state your intent of writing this function? What is that you are exactly trying to achieve? Maybe there is a better way to do it. Please add a brief description of how and where you intent to use this (Shooting in the dark, try moving deletion of the window widget after you are done reading/processing the spin button values)